# ¿Cómo exportar e importar en formato CSV desde MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, csv

Tengo la base datos llamada

```
sr_usuarios
```

esta contiene mil registros
ejemplo

```
usuario edad Ciudad
Juan    13   Caracas
Juan    17   Valencia
Juan    18   Guarico
Juan    19   Pto. Ordaz
```

Quiero exportar a CSV con comas como separadores e importar desde CSV mi pregunta es:

¿Cómo se hace suponiendo que la estructura de la tabla es la siguiente?

```
CREATE TABLE sr_usuarios
(
usuario Varchar (256), 
edad int,
Ciudad Varchar (256)
);
```

todo esto necesito hacerlo por medio de un boton input desde php, ¿como se hace?

Comment: Prueba con esta web:
[http://file2sql.com](http://file2sql.com?utm_source=es.stackoverflow&utm_medium=reply&utm_campaign=csv_mysql) A partir de un fichero csv detecta tipos de datos y retorna un script mysql que crea la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer con esta simple consulta, diciendo que parametros quieres, el nombre de tu archivo(bueno la ruta y el nombre de tu archivo), seguido de las restricciones tales que separa en comas cada columna y los saltos de linea, espero te sirva esto.

```
SELECT usuario,edad,ciudad
FROM sr_usuarios
INTO OUTFILE 'usuarios.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

Para las exportaciones desde linea de comando puedes usar lo siguiente

Ver: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty
FROM orders
WHERE foo = 'bar'
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Aunque los nombre de columnas no seran exportados asi....